# Getting an Array error message

Tags: java, arrays

I'm just starting java programing and I've been doing really good so far. So the program I am having problems with works just after it goes through there is an error message, yet the program worked as I wanted it to. 
The program in question is supposed to role a die 1000 times and count how many times each side of the die was rolled out of 1000. its supposed to display this, which it does.

Here is my program: and the error message I put below it. Thanks for any help in advanced!

```
public class Test
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {//create array of 1,000 random numbers
         int[] randomNumbers = new int[1000];

         for(int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++)
             randomNumbers[i] =1 +(int)(Math.random() * 6);
         { //initialize count
             int[] counts = countInts(randomNumbers);
             displayIntCount(counts);
         }
     }

     public static int[] countInts(int[] ints)
     { //creat new array to hold occurence values
         int[] counts = new int[6];
         for(int i = 1; i <=counts.length; i++)
             for(int j=0;j<ints.length;j++)
                 if(ints[j] == i)
                     counts[i-1]++;  
         return counts;
     }

     public static void displayIntCount(int[] counts)
     {//display the occurrences
         for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
                 System.out.println("The number 1 occurs "+counts[i]+" times \nThe number 2 occurs "+counts[i+1]+" times \nThe number 3 occurs "+counts[i + 2]+ " times \nThe number 4 occurs " +counts[i+3]+ " times \nThe number 5 occurs " +counts[i + 4]+ " times \nThe number 6 occurs "+counts[i + 5]+ " times");
     }
}
```

Comment: Don't forget the error message.

Comment: **What does the error _say_?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making mistake in displayIntCount(), I made the change for you:

```
public class Test
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {//create array of 1,000 random numbers
      int[] randomNumbers = new int[1000];

      for(int i = 0; i < randomNumbers.length; i++)
      randomNumbers[i] =1 +(int)(Math.random() * 6);
      { //initialize count
       int[] counts = countInts(randomNumbers);
       displayIntCount(counts);
      }
     }

    public static int[] countInts(int[] ints)
        { //creat new array to hold occurence values
         int[] counts = new int[6];
         for(int i = 1; i <=counts.length; i++)
             for(int j=0;j<ints.length;j++)
                 if(ints[j] == i)
                     counts[i-1]++;  
         return counts;
        }

     public static void displayIntCount(int[] counts)
      {//display the occurrences
         for (int i = 0; i < counts.length; i++)
             System.out.println("The number "+ (i+1) +" occurs "+counts[i]+ " times");
    } 
}
```

You have only 6 elements in the array and after running 6 times, you are running out of index!

Comment: Probably should be `"The number "+(i+1)` in displayIntCount()

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried to upvote you but I need a reputation of like 15 I guess. but when I get there I will upvote you!

Answer (score 1):

For clarification, the exception is:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at Test.displayIntCount(Test.java:38)
    at Test.main(Test.java:20)
Java Result: 1`

The problem is in `displayIntCount()`, you're looping through with `i` up until the last index in the array - but then trying to access `i+1` through to `i+5`.

You *probably* want to therefore change the condition to `counts.length-5`. In this case it *seems* like the program just works because the exception causes it to bow out and fail to print anything (and since this was a case you shouldn't have hit so didn't want to print anything anyway, the normal output stays ok.)